# Bootstrap grid - have empty columns on the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a bootstrap grid that is a set number of columns (be it 3 or 4 or 6 columns), can I use CSS in any way to ensure the empty columns are on the left rather than the right or do I need to add empty entries into the left hand columns?

So if the column count is 4 (`col-xs-3`) and I have 5 entries, I want the first row to be `value|value|value|value` and then the second row would be `empty|empty|empty|value`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to stub in empty columns, you can push the entire div to the right via offset. Just use a `.col-md-offset-9` to push it to the right:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">All of the way on the right.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I do that when I am dynamically building the contents? Cosmetically, I get the result I want by putting `float:right;` on the `col-xs-3` div but the contents are reversed

Comment: Downvoter: If I'm wrong in understanding the theory and you can explain the downvote, please do so.. I'd love to know

Comment: @Mike I'm guessing your "empty space" issue will happen more than once per row occasionally. You'll want to keep track of total row space left. I'm guessing that you'll need to use some combination of the mod operator and combinations of 3, as well as the balance of `(12 - used_space)`. It's hard to give specifics without seeing the issue in context.. but that should really be a separate question.